# how to increase memory usage manually?

Tags: solaris, memory

There is Solaris 10 OS on our server, and I would like to make test on this server. For this test memory usage should be high.

So I wonder if there is an easy way to increase memory usage manually ?

Comment: By "usage" you mean just allocated, or memory in use (like during a stress test)?

Comment: I mean emory in usage as you said like a stress test.

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer ? Anything wrong with it ?

Comment: @jlliagre I think your answer is good for memory allocation. It will not help for stress test. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it help ? You can create files there up to make the system stressed enough to be almost unresponsive or worst.

Comment: @jlliagre the file system that is reserved for /tmp is around  500 mb. But the free memory space is around 750 MB. I can not create a file bigger than 500 mb.

Comment: Not under the default configuration. You might be using the `-o size=500m` mount_tmpfs option (see /etc/vfstab) in which case you just need to remove it from there and reboot.

Comment: @jlliagre using memory is not the same as stressing it - I think that is the point here.

Comment: @mibzer, you should better explain what your goal is and possible edit your question to clarify what kind of memory (RAM, swap area or both, i.e. virtual memory) you want to use and what you want to measure or specifically stress. Stressing memory doesn't make much sense, to summarize, either you stress RAM and you are CPU bound or you exhaust your RAM and you stress your swap devices, i.e. you are I/O bound. In any case, mkfile doesn't only do memory allocation. It also writes it once so all pages are mapped to RAM. This is memory stressing to me.

Comment: @mibzer: jillagre's method is valid. The best way to use up RAM is to put a large file in a ramdisk. Solaris' default configuration is to have /tmp mounted as a ramdisk. If your system is different than the default just create another ramdisk.

Comment: A small correction, tmpfs is not strictly a ramdisk but a "virtual memory" disk. i.e. it will use RAM first but leave it for swap space in case of RAM demand.

Comment: Hi Everyone, sory for late response. Currently I can say that occupying space under /tmp did help to use RAM disk. But not as much as I want. What I was want was, increase as much as I can the RAM usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to fill /tmp, assuming it is using tmpfs which is the default. Run `df -k /tmp` to make sure it is.

To increase your (virtual) memory usage by 1 GB, run

```
mkfile 1g /tmp/1g
```

release it with

```
rm /tmp/1g
```

Comment: The command `mkfile` seems to be Solaris specific, other systems may provide `fallocate` which is similar.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez: I believe freebsd and OS/X have mkfile too. The question is Solaris specific anyway.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: This question is specifically about Solaris, but if you need to do this on Linux use `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/1g bs=1m count=1024`

Comment: if your `/tmp/` is size restricted in /etc/vfstab, you can create your file in `/var/run` and be able to consume more memory.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html) should help you.
Just small program in c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int max = -1;
    int sleep_interval = 2;
    int mb = 0;
    char* buffer;

    if(argc > 1)
        max = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(argc > 2)
        sleep_interval = atoi(argv[2]);

    while((buffer=malloc(1024*1024)) != NULL && mb != max) {
        memset(buffer, 0, 1024*1024);
        mb++;
        printf("Allocated %d MB\n", mb);
    }
    printf("sleeping for %d\n",sleep_interval);
    sleep(sleep_interval);
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that without giving the program a maximum amount of memory it'll allocate until it exhausts the amount it can (may be limited by ulimit, amount of memory, or size of address space).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know to fill memory is to make a program that allocates an array of strings (or arrays of any other type), if you need to keep the data in memory and not paged, you should scan the allocated memory periodically.

I would add a long (perhaps controlled by a command line argument) sleep interval after the allocation.

I would run several instances of the above program until I fill the desired amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir /ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=500G tmpfs /ramdisk
cp from_disk /ramdisk
```

- that will make a folder at the root level called `/ramdisk`, it will be file system transparent in that it acts like a normal directory, but the contents of the folder will reside in RAM
- change the number of 512 to be some amount less than the total physical RAM on your server, which will suit your needs; for example my server has 512GB of RAM so I use a value of 500
- this is dynamic, so only if you copy stuff into the `tmpfs` mounted folder will RAM usage happen, which can be monitored a variety of ways
- anything under the `tmpfs` mounted folder will be gone after system reboot, because the storage space was RAM
- I generally use a 4GB iso file of something like a linux install, and just re-copy it from disk using a script to something like `cp /home/ron/openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD-x86_64.iso /ramdisk/test1.iso` but you can do this any number of ways to suit your needs.
- I believe most linux kernels since 2.6 this `tmpfs` mount option, you will know immediately if the mount command fails with the `-t tmpfs` option; as a first try simply do `mount -t tmpfs -o size=2GB tmpfs /some_folder` and then do something like a `df` and you will see the `tmpfs` mount point along with amount *used*, *available*, and *% used*

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this works with Solaris, too - but since it is designed to run on Posix compliant systems you could give it a try: [**stress**](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/) is a very "simple" stress-test generator, that can do all sorts of stress - creating memory hogs is part of it.

I compiled/tested it so far on some Linux distributions (CentOS, SLES) without problems.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (I don't know if it works on Solaris too):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $EUID > 0 ]]; then # we can compare directly with this syntax.
  echo "Please run as root/sudo!"
  exit 1
fi

BS=100M
MNT=/mnt/tmp
FILE=${MNT}/mem-hog
FS_SIZE=8G
LOG=${0}.log-$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S')
SLEEP=5s

function onExit {
  test "mountpoint -q ${MNT}" && umount ${MNT}
  echo "Bye!" | ts | tee -a ${LOG}
}

trap onExit EXIT

mount -t tmpfs -o size=${FS_SIZE} none ${MNT} || exit $?

[ -f ${FILE} ] && (rm ${FILE} || exit $?)

COUNT=0

while [ true ]; do
  COUNT=$((COUNT + 1))
  echo -e "\n>> Allocation step #${COUNT} <<\n" | ts | tee -a ${LOG}

  dd if=/dev/zero bs=${BS} count=1 2> /dev/nul 1>> ${FILE} || exit $?

  echo "" | ts | tee -a ${LOG}
  free -m | ts | tee -a ${LOG}

  echo "" | ts | tee -a ${LOG}
  df -h ${MNT} | ts | tee -a ${LOG}

  sleep ${SLEEP}
done
```